# How to extract data from Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to extract all objects(See picture below) from Firebase Firestore. How can I add the output result into a dictionary?

```
func getLinks() {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let userID = user?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    print(userID!)
    let docRef = db.collection("files").document(userID!)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }

}
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXRD3.png)

Comment: You can save the response in a dictionary. And then extract that by using the key.If u want code snippet i can help you

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore I would be really thankful if you could help me with this

Comment: So my Question is do you want data key wise.?. Or need data of any firebase specific user key.? I mean you can see you have fetched the data for all the user.?

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore all the name values for every key

Comment: I have tried writing a piece of code for you, kindly look into this.

Answer (score 0):

### Fetch Data from Firebase and then Use it

**Step:-1** Fetch Data

```
    var dictData = [String:Any]() 
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value!)
        self.dictData = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]
        print(self.dictData)
       
    })
```

**Step:- 2** Extract the Data from SnapShot

```
var arrFetchedData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    
    for data in dictData{
        print(data.key) //Key will be printed here
        
        var tempDict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        
        let innerData = data.value as! [String:Any]
        
        let expires = innerData["expires"]
        tempDict.setValue(expires, forKey: "expires")
        let name = innerData["name"]
        tempDict.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        let url = innerData["url"]
        tempDict.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
        arrFetchedData.add(tempDict)
    }
    
    print(arrFetchedData) //All the Fetched data will be here
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: It says: Cast from '[String : Any]?' to unrelated type 'NSArray'  always fails and Value of type 'Any' has no member 'key' and Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Comment: @icodedev The answer has been edited in detail, Please look into this. Lemme know if it works for you.?